# how to run java annotation program on command line?

Tags: java

I want to run java annotation program on command line. I am unable to run the program.
Here is the program

```
package com.lara.annontations;
@interface F
{
    public String somemessage();
}
class G 
{
    @F(somemessage="My First Method")
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

I compiled the program using the command as
javac com/lara/annotations/G.java
it compiled successfully but i am facing problem in running the program. I used the command to run program as
java com.lara.annotation G 
but it is not working.
Please can anybody help me to run this program.
Thank you.

Comment: How do you know it's not working?

Comment: Define "not working". What did you expect? What actually happened? If an error, show the error message.

Answer (score 0):

1st you should define the retention of the annotation to RUNTIME... 
And you need to use reflection to print the meta-data you just annotated to the method

```
G gClass = new G(); 
Method m = gClass.getClass( ).getMethod("main"); 
Annotation[] annos = m.getAnnotations();
System.out.println("All annotations for myMeth:"); 
for(Annotation a : annos)
    System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: Why do you create a `G` instance if you only want to access a _static_ method?